# Connect HP LaserJet 1010 to Asus RT-AC87U (router) via USB and print from Windows 11

Tags: router, windows-11, printer, hp-laserjet, asus

*(To make a long story short: It did not work and then I decided to split the problem into 2: To try to print when the printer is connected via USB to the computer, and only when it works, to proceed to network installation)*.

#### USB - OK

I attempted to use the instructions provided [here](https://hplaserjet1010onwindows10.blogspot.com/2015/08/instructions-to-install-drivers-for-hp.html), but the printer did not print. Subsequently, I came across a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGZX08OWZ2w) and modified the driver to hp *LaserJet 1010 HB*. Following this adjustment, I successfully printed from my *Windows 11 Pro for Workstations* computer.

#### Network

Using the same *LaserJet 1010 HB* driver, I attempted the network solution by connecting the printer to the USB port at the back of the router (Asus RT-AC87U). I followed the instructions provided [here](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/114024), but unfortunately, the document doesn't leave the queue and the printer doesn't print.

How to debug this case?

Comment: Does your printer have an IP ?

Comment: @hidigoudi, as per Asus's instructions (https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/114024), it is necessary to input the IP address of the router. However, since the printer is a USB printer, it doesn't acquire its own IP address.

Comment: Have you installed successfully the `ASUS EZ printer sharing utility` on your Windows ?

Comment: @hidigoudi , it is written in the image above, that there are "two methods": 1) EZ printer sharing, 2) LPR to share a printer. - I used method 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At last, it's operational.** The *HP LaserJet 100* printer is connected to the *Asus RT-AC87U* router, and I can now use it from two computers (*Windows 11 Pro* over Wifi and wired *Windows 11 Pro for Workstations*).

What steps did I take?

1. Download and install the "HP Universal Print Driver for Windows - PCL 5": ***upd-pcl5-x64-6.1.0.20062.exe***. On the "Install the printer driver" I selected: "*HP Universal Printing PCL 5 (v6.1.0)*".
2. [Download from HP](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/hp-laserjet-1010-printer-series/306505) and extracted the "HP LaserJet 1010" driver for *Windows Vista (64-bit)*: ***lj1010serieshb-vista64***.
3. Add a new printer according to the ***[instructions](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/114024)*** by Asus. But with some customizations:

    * Step 8: Put the correct router's *IP Address* and a *Prot Name* with relevance (for instance: lj1010).

    * Step 10: (Contrary to the instructions provided in this paragraph) Open the "Have Disk..." dialog, navigate to the extraction folder and choose the "hp LaserJet 100 HB" driver.

    * Step 11: Give the printer a normal name: "HP LaserJet 1010 (Network)"

--

- During the effort to make it work, I installed ***Asus EZ Printer***, though I'm unsure of its contribution.
- Looking back, I'm unsure of step-1 contribution.

--

**At the end of all things:**

[image]

Click on the printer:

[image]

Properties (Windows 11 Pro):

[image]

[image]

On the router side (Asus RT-AC87U):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know a Laserjet 1010 is a so-called Win-printer.
Win-printers don't have a fully capable render-engine build in, but rely on a software-engine, that is part of the Windows driver, to do the heavy lifting.

It can only work with the HP drivers installed on the computer to which its USB port is physically connected. (The software engine needs to be able to talk to the printer directly via USB.)

When you have it installed to a Windows computer you can share it to other computers as a regular Windows "Shared Printer", but attaching it to a non-Windows machine (like your router) that can't run the special driver just won't work.